# Screen on/off validate from android shell

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm stuck at some validation for screen off and on test. I am using input keyevent 26 to put screen off and the same to wakeup. How to validate this test whether it was passed or failed. Is there any file where android write the state of the screen? any other way from dumpsys power? Can any one please suggest the way to check the state.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a simple app that has a broadcast receiver for the SCREEN ON and SCREEN OFF events, and log the events to the LogCat, and easily see it via `adb logcat`.

Here is some sample code for that. Make sure your app has been run at least once on the device, or it will not be registered for receiving the broadcast.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private boolean SCREEN_ON = false;  

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            SCREEN_ON = true;
            Log.d(C.TAG, "Screen on");
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            SCREEN_ON = false;
            Log.d(C.TAG, "Screen off");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raghav for your input. But all i want to do it from shell, rather than using an app.

Comment: You can install and launch the app from the shell; it needn't be interactive.

Comment: I got your intention Chris.. but i am looking for a faster way to get the result.